# Guzzle(cURL?) behaves differently on server and local

Tags: php, docker, curl, guzzle

I'm sending a request to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) from PHP script with Guzzle lib. On my local machine - everything works, but on a production server I get an error from FCM service: `411 Content-Length required`.

I've checked PHP version, Guzzle lib version, cURL version - they're all same between two machines. 
My project runs with a docker, so the environment is also same. And here the code how I'm sending a message to FCM:

```
    $handler = new CurlHandler();
    $stack = HandlerStack::create($handler);
    $config['handler'] = $stack;
    $client = new Client($config);
    try {
        $client->post($this->apiUrl, [
            RequestOptions::JSON => $data,
            RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
                'Authorization' => sprintf('key=%s', "key"),
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (TransferException $e) {
        throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }
```

I know there's not enough details to solve the problem, so ask for more if you need. Also, maybe any ideas how to represent this bug on my local machine?

I've already tried to put `Content-Length` header in my request, it's has not helped.

**UPD**

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN apk --update --no-cache add libmcrypt-dev libmcrypt curl-dev libcurl \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql mbstring curl


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/project
```

**UPD2**:

I've decided to try without the guzzle:

```
$curl = sprintf("curl -i -X POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -H 'Authorization: key=%s' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '%s'", $message->getSender(), $data);
exec($curl, $output);
```

And the result is same. When I run that script in bash on a production machine - everything ok. But when I run it from PHP - I get the same error "411 Content-Length required".

Comment: I'm confused. If you're using docker, why would you be checking if software versions are the same on 'two machines'? Have you got these things installed in docker? Can we see your dockerfile?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I meant that I checked versions of the software inside the docker containers. I've just updated my question with Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

It was a very stupid bug. In my real application I have something like this:

```
   try {
        $client->post($this->apiUrl, [
            RequestOptions::JSON => $data,
            RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
                'Authorization' => sprintf('key=%s', $key->getKey()),
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (TransferException $e) {
        throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }
```

So the problem was in this line: `$key->getKey()`. I store authorization key in the database. And on my production machine that key was stored with an extra line break symbol("\n"). So in the result request was looked like this:

```
Authorization: my key

Content-Length: 241
```

After I removed extra "\n" all works correctly:

```
Authorization: my key
Content-Length: 241
```